# Suggesting multiple labels prediction for multi-class training data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python

I have a dataset of tickets the machine gets for some machine components failure. The ticket are in text form.

For each failure we have around 8-10 diagnosis labels. This tells what the issue might have been and being used to fix the ticket.

Now in the training data I have one ticket and 1 diagnosis label. So it's a Multi-class training data.

After training a multi-class ML model, given a new text issue, can I suggest top 5 diagnosis for that possible ticket based on ranking of probabilities?

My concern is this makes sense for multi-label data where training data also has multiple labels and u can put sigmoid activation in the end to get proper prob of each diagnosis working for that ticket.

But if training data is framed as multi-class (meaning one ticket had only one corresponding label to it), is it still ok for me to suggest multiple diagnosis labels as rank order?

Thanks